# abs and mpvar^integer error in Xpress mosel

Tags: mosel

[image]

This is my code and:

[image]

this is error statement of code.

How can I solve those errors?

Comment: There is no image attached. But I suspect you are defining your terms as linctr's, but you are using nonlinear evaluations. You should use nlctr, and try to solve the nonlinear problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of `abs()` only accepts numbers. In order to make `abs()` for for expressions, you have to include the `mmxnlp` module. This is explained in the documentation [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/secothent_sec_ssecgenctr.html).

Note that this will change the type of your constraints from `linctr` to `nlctr`, so you have to change that in your code as well.

Finally, strict inequality is not supported. Instead `>` is interpreted as boolean operator. For a constraint you have to `>=`. If you really need the expressions to be different from zero then there is no other option than to use an epsilon: replace `> 0` by `>= eps` for a small number `eps`.